# Sets of equalities and inequalities constraint satisfiability problem

Tags: constraints, constraint-programming, constraint-satisfaction, satisfiability

I am relatively new to CSPs and I am trying to find the value of all the variables from their respective domains, based on ==, >, < and != constraints imposed between the variables.
I looked at Choco and Jacop but, I couldn't find out more about solving these type of problems.
Could you please point me to somewhere I can find an implementation of this example?
I have solved this using Prolog, but I want to use OOP to get this done.

Thank You.

Comment: Drools Planner (open source, java) is not a pure CSP, but it does solve the same problems and allow you to define your constraints in true OOP style, so with the ability to reuse methods like HolidayHelper.isHoliday(day, country) in your constraints. There are several examples and a detailed reference manual, but no SAT example yet afaik (shouldn't be too hard).

Comment: What are the types/domains of your variables? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

The type of problem you are describing is a direct description of a constraint programming problem, given that the variables have finite domains that can be mapped to integers.

All CP systems have the operators you need for operating over finite domain integers, so it should be straightforward.

If you are trying to solve for variables with unbounded domains or real domains, then there are some tools that can help you but they are not as common.